# How to Improve the model accuracy in face detection using MTCNN with tensorflow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am doing face detection using tensorflow with MTCNN detection. successfully I got the face detection and found the number of detected faces. In the detection module some of the faces have not detected.
How can I resolve that and How do I want to improve the model accuracy or confidence score.

I am thinking, if I can change the hyper parameters i.e learning rate to improve the model accuracy
or again I need to train from starting onwards by changing the hyper parameters.
Can I train this model on another dataset. is this going to increase the model accuracy ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways that I am aware of which you can use to improve your model accuracy:

1. First, you need to identify if you are laking accuracy in your training or in your testing set. If you are getting less accuracy in your training set then you should change the hyperparameters or add more layers to your model or may change your data (if it is all noise because sometimes you can get the best accuracy what you are already getting).
2. Second, if you are lacking in your testing set then try adding more data to your model. It is probably your overfitting your model.

NOTE: You should always finetune your model no matter what the data is.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you say how to create annotation file for the data(images),@Bhushan Pant